# Send multi-statement query in BigQuery api

Tags: google-bigquery, google-apis-explorer

Is it possible to send a multi-statement query, for instance:

```
"query" : "
CREATE TEMP TABLE cte_1 AS 

  SELECT *
    , GENERATE_UUID() AS flag
  FROM `my_project.my_dataset.user_visits_temp_islands_and_gaps`
;
SELECT flag FROM cte_1 
EXCEPT DISTINCT 
SELECT flag FROM cte_1 
"
```

and get the last statement's result?

Comment: Hi, when you try that, what happens?

Comment: By "send" do you mean using BigQuery REST API "jobs.query" method?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can send multiple statement query in BigQuery API and result for the last statement will return.

The queries needs to be separated with semicolon and the they'll will run sequentially.